# Django MPTT order_by error

Tags: django, django-mptt

models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gfx/category/image/', blank=True, null=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name',]
```

My view:

```
categories = Category.tree.filter(level__lte=1)
```

I will order by "created" in the first level of the tree in my template - How do I do so?
I tried:

```
categories = Category.tree.filter(level__lte=1).order_by('-created')
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have  parent

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
```

`parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')`

[blog.v-live.pl - more django tips](http://blog.v-live.pl)